# Insert images to Entry or Editor [Xamarin.Forms]

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is there any way to add images to `Entry` or `Editor` in `Xamarin Forms`?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: did you find anything on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3" Padding="0,10,0,0">
    <local:MyFrame BackgroundColor="Transparent" OutlineColor="White" HasShadow="false" Padding="20,5,5,5">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Source="Username.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Start" />

    <local:MyEntry Placeholder="UserName / PhoneNo" x:Name="Entry"       BackgroundColor="Transparent" PlaceholderColor="White" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White"  FontSize="15"    HeightRequest="40" />
</Grid>
</local:MyFrame>
```

In this way, you can add an image In-front of the entry field. If you need it in top of the `EntryField`. You can Set the grid position same for both entry and image. Then set Height and width Request Accordingly.

```
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99140/how-to-place-icon-before-entry-control
```

Using this link You can have an idea how to this

Comment: Thanks, but I need to insert image like emoji inside entry/editor middle of text (delete with keyboard etc)

Comment: you need to add an image like in the photo i uploaded

Comment: You can add image to entry or editor using custom renderer. Or you can use the @C_Subash suggestion and keep an image near the entry. Is this your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to insert image in Entry control, you can create custom entry, please take a look this article:

https://xamgirl.com/image-entry-in-xamarin-forms/

If you want to add emoji in Entry, and delete it, I suggest you can set Keyboard=chat for Entry:

```
<Entry Keyboard="Chat" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry

Answer (score 0):

The PhantomLib library has an entry control that allows you to have an icon that clears the entered text when the user taps it. It also has the ability to have an icon for showing/hiding password text. You can use it as is via nuget or look at the source and modify. https://github.com/OSTUSA/PhantomLib